# Having difficulty with find/closest

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

**UPDATE 1:**

Am I getting this problem because I am removing `.BC1` before the `get_firm_summary();` can use it?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I've started this question over again as it wasn't structured well and was causing lots of confusion.

Before I get started, I would like to point out that I am using jQuery 1.4

I have a function where I dynamically create a `span` tag within some HTML where the `span` tag looks something like this:

`<span class='BC1'>some text here</span>`

The HTML before `.BC1` is inserted looks like this:

```
<div class="portlet_10">
    <div class="portlet_header_10"></div>
    <div class="portlet_sub_header_10">this is where the span gets inserted</div>
    <div class="portlet_content_10">this is the bit which should get cleared and appended with new data</div>
    <div class="portlet_footer_10"></div>
<div>
```

And it looks like this after `.BC1` is inserted:

```
<div class="portlet_10">
    <div class="portlet_header_10"></div>
    <div class="portlet_sub_header_10"><span class="BC1">some text here</span></div>
    <div class="portlet_content_10">this is the bit which should get cleared and appended with new data</div>
    <div class="portlet_footer_10"></div>
<div>
```

I then have a `click` event for this `.BC1` tag:

```
$('.BC1').live('click', function() {
    alert("clicked");
    $(this).closest('.portlet_10').find('.portlet_sub_header_10').empty();  
    get_firm_summary( $(this) );
});
```

The alert and finding the closest `portlet_sub_header_10` and setting it to `empty();` works, as the inserted `.BC1` disappears.  I am having a problem with the `get_firm_summary( $(this) );`

The function looks something like this:

```
function get_firm_summary( that ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_firm_summary.aspx?rand=' + Math.random(),
        type: 'GET',
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(status);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        },
        success: function(results) { 
            console.log( that.attr("class") );
            that.closest('.portlet_10').find('.portlet_content_10').empty().append( results );
        }
    });
}
```

Here the console.log works fine, but nothing happens to `portlet_content_10`.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: do you get `portlet_content_10` empty or not changing at all ?

Comment: @mgraph, nothing in `portlet_content_10` changes at all, so it does not empty or change at all.

Comment: @mgraph, how do I check trace(results), I've never used this before.

Comment: sorry i mean `console.log(results);` `trace` is for flash

Comment: @mgraph, `console.log( results );` returns everything I want it to insert into `.portlet_content_10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because before you call `get_firm_summary( $(this) );` you are calling `empty()` on the parent div of the clicked element. This is losing the reference to the element in the DOM, rendering any traversal functions impossible.

Try this:

```
$('.BC1').live('click', function() {
    get_firm_summary( $(this) );
});

// ajax:
success: function(results) {
    // add new text
    that.closest('.portlet_10').find('.portlet_content_10').empty().append("FOO BAR");

    // remove clicked element
    that.closest('.portlet_10').find('.portlet_sub_header_10').empty();  
}
```

See this fiddle for a [**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/GceMW/)

Comment: That was it, i.e. removing the span tag too early.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for better solution

```
$('.BC1').live('click', function() {
    alert("clicked");
    get_firm_summary( $(this) );
    $(this).closest('.portlet_10').find('.portlet_sub_header_10').empty();  

});
```